# How does visual studio 2003 detect assemblies specific to .net framework 1.1?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

When i install VS2003 and VS2005/2008 on the same machine. All DLLs goes to the GAC. So GAC contains .net 1.1 and .net 2.0/3.5 dlls.

When i load visual studio 2003,how does it reference only 1.1 dlls. how does it resolve ambiguity as multiple versions with same name exists.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because assembly references in general can contain a version number, so each and every reference by itself is (or at least can be) version sensitive...

Thomas

Comment: if that is the case,why did .net 4.0 create a new GAC instead of placing them inside previous GAC.

Comment: 4.0 did create a new GAC? Didn't know that - do you mean a new file system folder called GAC? Not sure about that, but references generally work this way...